# Creating a loop in MATLAB to find means

Tags: matlab

So I have 2 matrices in MATLAB. If one of them is a 100 X 2 matrix, like this:

```
[a b]
[13 19]
[21 39]
[35 45]
```

ect. ect.

and the other matrix is a N X 1 matrix with values like this:

```
[1]
[3]
[5]
[7]
```

ect. ect.

What I'm trying to do is find the Mean value of all the elements from 'a' to 'b' of the 2nd matrix.

What I've got so far is this:
(If my first matrix is called: MATRIX1

second matrix is called: MATRIX2)

```
a= MATRIX1(1:1)
b= MATRIX1(1:2)
values = MATRIX2(a:b)
mean(values)
```

this gives me exactly what I want, the mean of the values from a to b. 
But how do I create a loop so that I can do this automatically for all the rows in MATRIX 1?

Thanks!

Update: 
I figured out how to get a loop, but now I'm not sure how to take all my values and make it into a 100 X 1 matrix. This is the code I used:

```
c= size(MATRIX1,1);

for k= 1:c;
    a= MATRIX1(k,1);
    b= MATRIX1(k,2);
    values= MATRIX2(a:b);
    d= mean(values)
end
```

with this, I get 100 values of d. How do I put these values into a 100 X 1 matrix?

Comment: I am trying to create a 3rd 100 X 1 matrix (same # of rows as MATRIX 1) which contains the mean values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to do this with a [for loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f4-1931.html#brbss8u-1):

```
nRows = size(MATRIX1,1);
meanValues = zeros(nRows,1);
for row = 1:nRows
  meanValues(row) = mean(MATRIX2(MATRIX1(row,1):MATRIX1(row,2)));
end
```

Another way to do this is to use the function [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) like so:

```
meanValues = arrayfun(@(a,b) mean(MATRIX2(a:b)),MATRIX1(:,1),MATRIX1(:,2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I'm already beaten, but just for the sake of variety, another option using `cellfun` is:

```
cellfun(@(pair) mean(x(pair(1):pair(2))), num2cell(inds, 2))
```

Comment: This is often a better approach since Matlab doesn't generally handle `for` loops efficiently

Comment: Note, however, that `cellfun` / `arrayfun` are often even more inefficient than `for` loops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143314/matlab-arrayfun-cellfun-spfun-and-structfun-vs-simple-for-loop

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there!

```
elems = 100
values = zeros(1, elems)
for row = 1:elems
  a= MATRIX1(1:1)
  b= MATRIX1(1:2)
  values(row) = MATRIX2(a:b)
end
mean(values)
```

Answer (score 3):

just for clarification you want something that takes the "a"th element in matrix 2 to the "b"th element and averages all of those values?

This should work:

```
[r c] = size(MATRIX1);
myMeans = zeros(r,1);

for i = 1:r
   myMeans(i) = mean(MATRIX2(MATRIX1(i,1):MATRIX1(i,2)))
end
```

this will store all of the means for the rows in myMeans